# How to show number of each row please ? JS csv

Tags: javascript, csv, parsing

I want to show the number of each row but i don't how to do it.

I tried something but it doesn't work.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const csv = require('fast-csv');

let count = 0;
fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets', 'parse.csv'))
    .pipe(csv.parse({ headers: true }))
    .on('error', error => console.error(error))
    .on('data', row => count++, console.log(count + row))
    .on('end', rowCount => console.log(`Parsed ${rowCount} rows`));
```

Comment: What csv parsing library are you using?

Comment: Does it work with `.on('data', () => { row => count++; console.log(count + row); })` instead?

Comment: fast-csv @CharlesBamford

Comment: I get this error "row is not defined" @SlavaKnyazev

Comment: You probably need `row => {count++; console.log([count, ...row])}`. The second argument for on is the callback to run when the "data" event is heard. Currently your callback increments count and returns it, then you pass a console.log() command as a third argument.  I don't believe node expects a third argument, so it discards it.

Comment: fast and efficient ! thank you @CharlesBamford